# How to specify "accepts generic sub-type of a generic type"?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

I am trying to implement a function definition that accepts a generic parameter, as long as it extends another specific generic type. In short; param A must extend param B, where A and B are both generic.

My sample example below

```kotlin
abstract class Endpoint<T>(
) {

    private val myList: MutableMap<Class<T>, MutableList<((T) -> Unit)>> = mutableMapOf()

    fun addToList(
        index: Class<E>, <-- E extends T
        value: (E) -> Unit
    ) {
        myList[index] = (myList[index] ?: mutableListOf()).apply { add(value) }
    }

}
```

Usage example would be

Some sealed class

```kotlin
sealed class MainSealedClass {
    data class ChildClass(val someParam: Int): MainSealedClass()
}
```

And the function call

```kotlin
anEndpointInstance.addToList(MainSealedClass.ChildClass::class.java, "some value")
```

I would like to not having to define E in the abstract class declaration, since T is already defined there.

I tried doing the following as well:

Define myList as accepting keys that extend T as such

```kotlin
val myList: MutableMap<Class<in T>, MutableList<String>>
```

Define E as a T type (couldn't find how to specify it extends T in the function

```kotlin
    fun <E:T> addToList(
        index: Class<E>,
        value: (E) -> Unit
    ) {
        myList[index] = (myList[index] ?: mutableListOf()).apply { add(value) }
    }
```

```kotlin
    fun addToList(
        index: Class<in T>,
        value: (E) -> Unit
    ) {
        myList[index] = (myList[index] ?: mutableListOf()).apply { add(value) }
    }
```

```kotlin
    fun <E> addToList(
        index: Class<E>,
        value: (E) -> Unit
    ) where E : T {
        myList[index] = (myList[index] ?: mutableListOf()).apply { add(value) }
    }
```

But it never works. Is there a way of achieving this? I could not find anything in StackOverflow that had an answer for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your variance inverted. If you want your map to accept Classes of subtypes of T, then it needs to be `<out T>`. If you're not inspecting the keys, you could probably just put `Class<*>`.

Your first way of declaring the function was correct.

```
abstract class Endpoint<T>(
) {

    private val myList: MutableMap<Class<out T>, MutableList<String>> = mutableMapOf()

    fun <E : T> addToList(
        index: Class<E>,
        value: String
    ) {
        myList.getOrPut(index, ::mutableListOf).add(value)
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, that did it alright. I was definitely confusing the `in` and `out` of generics, I thought each did the opposite of what they actually do.

Comment: @Shadow, by the way, I see a bug in your function. If the list at the index doesn't exist yet, you create a list and fill it with an item, but you neglected to put that new list into your map.

Comment: Not really, the ` myList[index] =` is an assignment of whichever result is in front, if there is a list then it returns that list, if there isn't, then it creates a new one and returns that one

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Are you aware of `getOrPut`? That line could become `myList.getOrPut(index, ::mutableListOf).add(value)`

Comment: Quick one, still the same example. How would I go about to do the same thing for specifying a (out T) -> Unit for a lambda? I've edited the question with that example. Or if you prefer I can post a new question just for this one

Comment: I've posted it as a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71914912