# How to specify in a lambda "accepts generic sub-type of a generic type"?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

This question is a derivative of a recent one I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71913498)

While that one was resolved, I immediately faced a new one of a similar nature, but I am also not able to find a solution for it.

Sample example:

```kotlin
abstract class Endpoint<T>() {

    private val myList: MutableList<(T) -> Unit> = mutableListOf()

    fun <E : T> addToList(cbk: (E) -> Unit) { <-- E extends T
        myList.add(cbk)
    }

}
```

Usage example would be

Some sealed class

```kotlin
sealed class MainSealedClass {
    data class ChildClass(val someParam: Int): MainSealedClass()
}
```

And the function call

```kotlin
anEndpointInstance.addToList<ChildClass>{it: ChildClass -> 
    // do something here
}
```

I tried doing the following, but it looks like it is not is not allowed

```kotlin
val myList: MutableList<(out T) -> Unit> <--- Unsupported error shows up
```

Is there a way to do this without having to add an extra declaration at the class level?

I considered using `inline reified` but the function needs to access private fields of the `Endpoint` instance, so I do not want to use that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tenfour04's knowledge, I was able to find a workaround to my issue. I do not consider this to be a fix for my issue, but given that it apparently cannot be done as I expected, the next best thing was to work around the issue with the help of a wrapper.

Here is how my code turned out with the work using the sample in my question

```kotlin
abstract class Endpoint<T>() {

    private val myList: MutableList<(T) -> Unit> = mutableListOf()

    fun add(cbk: (T) -> Unit) {
        myList.add(cbk)
    }

    inline fun <reified N : T> addToList(crossinline callback: (N) -> Unit) {
        add { if (it is N) callback.invoke(it) }
    }

}
```

And its usage is the way I wanted in my question, nothing changes at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the language supports specifying variance of the parameters of a functional type, or references to functions with generic types that aren't defined. For example, if you want to get a reference to a generic function, you have to specify its generic types in the functional type declaration.

There is dubious usefulness here anyway. If you had a list of functions that each have different input types, then when you retrieve a function from the list, you won't be able to call it because you won't know which input type it supports. You might as well have a `MutableList<Any>`.

Comment: Thanks to your explanation I believe I eventually found a way around this limitation using a wrapper that checks for the type expected by the lambda function. Perhaps "ensures" would be more appropriate than "checks" since that's the goal of it. Will test it further and then share the solution as an answer.